# Services Creating Services - Assigning SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE to a User

Tags: windows, winapi, service

I'm trying to create a Windows service that has the right to create additional services. But I'd prefer not to make this service run with an Administrative login.

The users rights are otherwise quite limited - I just need it to be able to spin-up a service on request.

I've seen mention online that SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE is a permission you can now assign and/or change, but I haven't seen much on **how** that is done. There is mention of being able to change permissions for individual services via subinacl, via OpenSCManager and the - *gulp* - sc command. But these examples show how to change the permissions on a single service, not how to give a user SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE permissions.

However, I've noticed that the documentation on CreateService specifically says that it requires administrator privilages - so perhaps it's simply not possible.

Am I going to have to start the service with an admin account? Or does anyone know another trick?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the LocalService account?

Comment: Nothing in the `CreateService()` documentation specifically states that admin privileges are needed (though that would make sense, since it writes to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in the Registry), only that `OpenSCManager()` must be called with `SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE` specified in the `dwDesiredAccess` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

See [Service Security and Access Rights:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx#access_rights_for_the_service_control_manager)

> To get or set the security descriptor for the SCM, use the QueryServiceObjectSecurity and SetServiceObjectSecurity functions with a handle to the SCManager object.

Be aware that having the right to create services gives you effective administrator access, since you can create a service to run as local system.  So you do need to be careful not to grant that right to accounts that untrusted users have access to, to make sure that all accounts with that right have strong passwords, and so on.

This also means that if your system service is compromised by a remote code execution vulnerability you haven't gained anything, the attacker will still be able to get control of your system.  If the service is at a high risk of direct attack, it may be wise to instead have a second service that is responsible only for the tasks that require special privilege.  However, for a service that is unlikely to be directly attacked, or is considered reasonably secure, running without administrator privileges (other than the ability to create services) may prevent a less severe vulnerability from being exploitable, or limit the damage caused by a non-security-related bug.

See also [Granting service control manager access permission to user outside of administrator group](https://serverfault.com/q/441015/94065) on Server Fault, the answer shows how to change the SCM permissions from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening an handle to the service control manager with the WRITE_DAC access right, and change the security of it by calling SetServiceObjectSecurity to change the dacl of the service control manager. Don't forget to do the same thing for the service registry key (HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services) using RegOpenKeyEx and RegSetKeySecurity function.

WARNING
Be aware that this is a potential security risk since it would allow a standard user account to elevate its privileges to SYSTEM.